# Perfecting a proof using Strong Mathematical Induction.

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

Finals are coming up and I am wondering what I can **add/ remove to perfect a proof** using the principle of strong mathematical induction. I've done a proof as an example. Any feed back welcome.

**Question**

Let the sequence $a_0, a_1, a_2,...$ be defined by the following recursive definition:
\begin{align*}
a_0&=1,\\[1.5ex]
a_1&=3,\\[1.5ex]
a_2&=6,\\[1.5ex]
a_k&=a_{k-1}+a_{k-2}+a_{k-3} \text{ for all integers $k \geq 3$}
\end{align*}
Use strong mathematical induction to prove that $a_n \leq 3^n$ for all integers $n \geq 0$

**Proof**

Let $P(n)$ be the predicate for $a_n \leq 3^n$. Thus, 
\begin{align*}
P(0)&=a_o\leq 3^0 \rightarrow 1\leq 1\\[1.5ex]
P(1)&=a_1\leq 3^1 \rightarrow 3\leq 3\\[1.5ex]
P(2)&=a_2\leq 3^2 \rightarrow 6\leq 9\\[1.5ex]
\end{align*}
We can see that $P(0)$, $P(1)$ and $P(2)$ hold. Let us assume $P(i)$ holds for $0\leq i \leq k$ where $k\geq 2$. Consider $P(k+1)$:
\begin{align*}
a_{k+1}&=a_{k}+a_{k-1}+a_{k-2}\\[1.5ex]
&\leq 3^k+3^{k-1}+3^{k-2}\\[1.5ex]
&=3^2\cdot 3^{k-2}+ 3\cdot 3^{k-2}+ 3^{k-2}\\[1.5ex]
&=3^{k-2}(3^2+3+1)\\[1.5ex]
&\leq 3^{k-2}\cdot 3^3=3^{k+1}
\end{align*}
Since $P(k+1)$ holds for $k \geq 2$ we conclude that by the principle of strong mathematical induction, $a_n\leq 3^n$ holds $\forall n \geq 0$.

Comment: Seems right to me

Comment: What's a perfect proof anyway. A correct proof is hard enough, isn't it?

Comment: That is very nicely done.  I'd like to give some advice but... I don't see that any is needed.  It's very well set up and executed.  I suppose I could say that you could use $(3^2 + 3+1) < 3^3$ but that's not necessary as you were not asked to prove that (although you could prove the stronger $a_k < 3^n$ for all $n \ge 2$.)

Comment: @Sudix As in, a proof following exactly the structure for PSMI. I feel like I need to be super picky with how I set out this type of proof.

Comment: @fleablood noted, thank you!

Comment: @LysanderM You mean the whole thing feels just too obvious, so you struggle to gauge the precise level of exactness that's required?

Comment: I might've written "where the final inequality follows because $3^2 + 3 + 1 = 13 < 27 = 3^3$," but it looks otherwise convincing! [Edit: If you want a really minor nitpick: You misspelled the word "integers"...]

Comment: Just set up the correct base cases, and set the proposal for $k+1$ and then express any lesser term in context of the proposition and ... carry through.  It's all in the set up.

Comment: @Sudix I don't think that it feels obvious is the right word, but yes you could say I struggle with how precise I need to be in my proof.

Comment: @BenjaminDickman My bad, fixed the spelling error. Also, that's a good point I'll take note thank you.